# flutter dropdownbutton index select all

Tags: flutter

this `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` 1st index click to icon `check_box_outlined` select to all index select or icon select

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                      child: DropdownButton2<String>(
                                        isExpanded: true,
                                        hint: Text(
                                          'Select Here',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            color: hintText,
                                            fontSize: 13.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          ),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                        items: lab.map((item) {
                                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: item,
                                            enabled: false,
                                            child: StatefulBuilder(
                                              builder: (context, menuSetState) {
                                                final isSelected = selectedLab.contains(item);
                                                return GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                     isSelected ? selectedLab.remove(item) : selectedLab.add(item);
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                    menuSetState(() {});
                                                  },
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    height: double.infinity,
                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                        .symmetric(
                                                        horizontal: 16),
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        if (isSelected)
                                                          const Icon(Icons.check_box_outlined)
                                                        else
                                                          const Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                                                        const SizedBox(
                                                            width: 16),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            item,
                                                            style: GoogleFonts
                                                                .poppins(
                                                              color: hintText,
                                                              fontSize: 13.sp,
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .w400,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                        //Use last selected item as the current value so if we've limited menu height, it scroll to last item.
                                        value: selectedLab.isEmpty ? null : selectedLab.last,
                                        onChanged: (value) {},
                                        selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
                                          return lab.map(
                                            (item) {
                                              return Container(
                                                alignment:
                                                    AlignmentDirectional.center,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  selectedLab.join(', '),
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  ),
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ).toList();
                                        },
                                        buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 16, right: 8),
                                          height: 40,
                                          width: 140,
                                        ),
                                        menuItemStyleData:
                                            const MenuItemStyleData(
                                          height: 40,
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
```

Comment: share formated code snippet.